# Semi detached house meaning

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Can the phrase semi detached house mean that a house is attached to other houses from both sides? Our English teacher told us that this is true, however on Wikipedia or on the Cambridge dictionary it is described as attached to a different house on only one side.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Surrounded by or attached to? Semi-detached means that it's attached to another house on one side but it might have other neighbors that don't attach to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Britain, a semi-detached house always means one of a pair, usually with left/right symmetry, and not attached to others. Houses joined in a row are, oddly, called ‘terraced’.

Comment: ..and the houses that are at the ends of a terrace are described as "end of terrace" rather than being "semi-detached" (despite the fact that they are only attached on one side).

Comment: In recent years there has been a design called Q type where four properties are arranged in a square block with one on each corner, so each property has two neighbours.

Comment: yeah a detached house has no neighbours attached, a semi detached could be called a semi-terrace as well, wonder why they chose semi-detached :)